# knockoutJS - rebind table from other javascript function

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS to display a list of users. On the same page a link triggers a shadowbox modal-window. When the user closes the modal I want the list of users to refresh. I already have the callback-function from the Shadowbox modal triggering, but how to make it refresh the list of users?

```
        function User(data) {
            this.firstname = ko.observable(data.firstname);
            this.lastname = ko.observable(data.lastname);
            this.fullname = ko.computed(function () {
                return this.firstname() + " " + this.lastname();
            }, this);
            this.userfunctions = ko.observable(data.userfunctions);
            this.phonework = ko.observable(data.phonework);
            this.phonemobile = ko.observable(data.phonemobile);
            this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
            this.editurl = ko.observable(data.editurl);
        }

        function UserListViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.users = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.users.loading = ko.observable(false);

            self.users.loading(true);
            $.getJSON("/UserJSON.ashx", {
                requestType: "userList",
                pageId: '12',
                companyId: '1'
            },
            function (allData) {
                var mappedUsers = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new User(item); });
                self.users(mappedUsers);
                self.users.loading(false);
            });
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new UserListViewModel());
```

Comment: Within the modal window, are you adding entries or modifying entries already there? And if modifying, are you modifying an actual instance within self.users or a new User object and then replacing the one within self.users once the person confirms (would suggest the second to allow for cancelling of changes). BTW, I assume you're intent is to refresh the list of users, you mean without having to go back to the /UserJSON.ashx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at knockout mapping?  It handles data updates from the server:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

I would create a "data" property on your viewmodel that gets loaded from knockout mapping, and can be updated from there. I'll work on a jsfiddle and update this answer.

**UPDATE**

I was working on a JSFiddle, but found one that was already done :-) (Thanks RP Niemeyer!)

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EDC7q/

**UPDATE 2**

I updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sb2BX/1/

to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/sb2BX/3/

See it work, first click "Load Initial Data", then click "Shadowbox Callback". Does this answer your question?

Comment: I've handled the loading of data from the server. I need to sort out how I can call the 'click: loadUpdatedData' from another js-function... I have a existing callback-function that is being called when I close a ShadowBox-modal.

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle?

Comment: I might be a little retarded right now but I dont see how that shows me how to call loadUpdatedData from another function. It just show me how to bind a click-event to a button that I dont have... See the updated fiddle. In the bottom you see my function. http://jsfiddle.net/sb2BX/1/